# jquery onchange event for radio button now instantaneous

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make an ID active only when a certain type of radio button is selected.  Below is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#Type').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   $('input[@name=action]').change(function() {
     if ($("input[@name=action]:checked").val() == 'SomeKind')              
        $('#Type').removeAttr('disabled');
     else 
        $('#Type').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

This works as intended but with one flaw.  When I click on the radio button `SomeKind` it does not make `Type` active instantaneously, instead I have to click again (anywhere on the page) for `Type` to be active.

I am on IE7

Comment: You have to write click method on your SomeKind radio button to activate/deactivate Type. currently nowhere mention that your are changing Type on change of SomeKind

Comment: click method is on the whole radio button with name action, then I check if the one selected is of SomeKind and then disable/enable Type. How else would I do it?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you on? 1.2.6?  And can you upgrade?

Comment: Yes. I'm on 1.2.6.  Is there a known bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if action is a name of your checkbox, then use click event instead of change,

```
$('input[@name=action]').click(function() {
     if (this.checked && $(this).val() == 'SomeKind')              
        $('#Type').removeAttr('disabled');
     else 
        $('#Type').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

IE7 has some odd issues with change events and radio buttons, the change event doesn't fire until there's a blur as well. I ran into similar issues once and, after much gnashing off teeth, found this:

> http://norman.walsh.name/2009/03/24/jQueryIE

You can use Chinmayee's `.click` approach (but check and double check that everything works properly when you use the keyboard rather than the mouse) or you can add a click handler to all your radio buttons that blurs and refocuses:

```
$(':radio').click(function() {
    try {
        this.blur();
        this.focus();
    }
    catch (e) {}
});
```

You only want this disgusting kludge for IE7 so you'd probably want to wrap it in a conditional comment (a kludge within a kludge). I'm pretty sure IE8's radio buttons have the same problem.